# Colliding with obstacles on a map

Tags: c++, 2d, collision, allegro5

I'm trying to make obstacles that stops the player after colliding. Simply, the walls.

I've created collision detection, like this:

```
if (x > (wall.x1 - wall.boundX) && x < (wall.x + wall.boundX) &&
    y >(wall.y1 - wall.boundY) && y < (wall.y + wall.boundY))
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;

}
```

but, as you can see, it just returns my player object to (0,0) on map (by the way, I'm using mouse to control my character). I want it to stop right where he collides and to be unable to move through this wall.

How can I do that?

Comment: do you know what the last position of the character was at before the collision?

Comment: That's the problem too, because the position of character is related to the mouse pointer position. It's like
"
if (x < move.x)
  {
   x += speed;
   if (x >= move.x)
    x = move.x;
  }
" and so on for the rest of the directions (x is the character's X, move.x is the mouse's X).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to separate your `if` statement to handle each wall separately, and then set the `x` or `y` position to the bounds of the wall:

```
if (x > wall.x1 - wall.boundX)
    x = wall.x1 - wall.boundX;

if (x < (wall.x + wall.boundX))
    x = wall.x + wall.boundX;

// etc
```

No matter how far the mouse attempts to move past the bounds of the wall, it will just remain at that position.